# What is a German programmer's "rubber duck"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang

I came across [this excerpt from answers](http://umumble.com/blogs/Programming/321/) of the now deleted stackoverflow question on new programming slang where it says:

> **Rubberducking**
>   Sometimes, you just have to talk a problem out; for example: Someone put a rubber duck on the monitor, so he could talk to it, therefore, rubberducking is talking your way through a problem.

Trying to translate this to German caused several headaches:

- [Leo](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=rubber%20duck) translates a *"rubber duck"* with: ***Badeente, Gummiente***.
- Both these terms are **not listed by Duden**.
- The corresponding [Wikipedia article](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badeente) linked it to  ***"Quietscheentchen"*** a term that is at least [known by Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Quietscheentchen).
- Still, there is not much help on deciding which of these terms is actually popular.
- A [Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Badeente,Quietscheentchen,Gummiente&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3) indicates that it may be ***Gummiente***.
- Finally, a research on [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Rubber%20Duck) revealed meanings we don't want to translate.

This where I got stuck.

Is there a well known German term for *"rubber duck"* that could be used in the context above? What would a German programmer say to his/her *"rubber duck"*, or for *"rubberducking"*?

Comment: Wtf? So on urban: "Floating pool or bath toy" -> Therefore you already gave all translations. But *Rubberducking: programmer talking to a rubber duck* ... That's a joke, isn't it? (PS: Ich hab ne Maus (Spielfigur) auf dem Monitorständer, aber ich red nicht mit dem Vieh)

Comment: [Das hier ergibt Sinn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Jetz versteh' ich worum es geht. Du kannst die Ente *Prüfer* nennen, von Code Review abgeleitet ;p

Comment: Bei [Loriot](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jOtOIOX3RI) ist es nur eine Ente - hat aber nichts mit Programmieren zu tun ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As a programmer I call the technique "rubber ducking" and I have no German translation for that meaning of the term.

I would translate "rubber duck" itself (i.e. the toy) as "Quietscheentchen" or "Badeente" as you already wrote, but I've never heard that translation used when referring to the technique.

It is relatively common in computer sciences/IT that english terms are simply used untranslated. Often there simply are no common, agreed-upon translations. In some cases the translations exist, but are used relatively rarely (Example: the "heap" memory structure is *sometimes* translated as "Haufenspeicher", but most software developers I know dislike this translation and prefer to use the original English term).

Comment: "Verklemmung" is nice as well. It's a deadlock.

Comment: As far as I know "stack memory" is translated as "Stapelspeicher" and "heap memory" as "Kellerspeicher".

Comment: And "array" is "Feld".

Comment: I'd definitely go with "Quietscheentchen" or "Quietscheente" in German, rather than any of the other versions. And we use it in our team, but we speak only English :)

Answer (score 11):

In our software development team, we use the term "Gummiente". Examples:

> "Ich brauch mal eine Gummiente."
>
> "Ich bin verwirrt." -- "Soll ich Deine Gummiente spielen?"

Comment: Interessant, ich würde nach Sprachgefühl "Quietscheentchen" oder "Quietscheente" bevorzugen. Aber wenn das aktiv benutzt wird, ist es ein Argument. +`1

Comment: Yes, I use that term too - not just in computing. When used by Ernie in the bath tub it is of course always *Quietscheentchen*, but outside Sesame Street *Gummiente* is at least as common. See [Google n-gram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Quietscheente%2CQuietscheentchen%2CGummiente%2CBadeente&year_start=1800&corpus=20&direct_url=t1%3B%2CQuietscheentchen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CGummiente%3B%2Cc0), though the data is not statistically significant.